# iOS : MapKit place an annotation relative to the map, and not the bounds of the screen

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

I am writing an application with a mapview inside.

I download coordinates for some **annotations** from my server via a HTTP request.
I am supposed to decode the JsonResponse and add the annotations to my map.

Excerpt from my JSON response

```
...{
    "id": 1,
    "lat": 20.34226,
    "long": 19.988363
},..
```

I add my annotations within this method, which is called when the download of the above JSON is complete. (i have a custom annotation class.)

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    // show all values
    for(NSDictionary *dict in res) {

        CGFloat a = [[dict objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
        CGFloat b = [[dict objectForKey:@"long"] floatValue];

//        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
//        location.latitude = a;
//        location.longitude = b;
//
        CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate
        = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(b,a) toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];


        MapViewAnnotation *myPin = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate]; // Or whatever coordinates...

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:myPin];
    }

}
```

When the annotations are added, they are added relative to my screens bounds , and not to the whole mapview.

I do understand that the method call `[self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(a,b) toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView]` is the cause of this.

I would like to perform the code that is now **in comments**, and skip the

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate
        = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(b,a) toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
```

and go directly for `MapViewAnnotation *myPin = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];`

However, when i do this i get the following error:

```
An instance 0x858cc30 of class MapViewAnnotation was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x1a000890> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x1a000850: Observer: 0xa117890, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1a0008d0>
)
```

What i wonder is: How can i add these annotations relative to my map, with long/latitude obtained from JSON (and not relative to the view i currently see).

Comment: That `location` code should work.  That error can happen if any of the lat/long values are invalid.  Uncomment the `location` code and put this NSLog before calling initWithCoordinate: `NSLog(@"lat=%f, long=%f", location.latitude, location.longitude);` and make sure all the latitudes are from -90 to 90 and the longitudes are from -180 to 180.  Also, not related, but I'd use double and doubleValue instead of CGFloat and floatValue for better precision (and CLLocationDegrees itself is a double).

Comment: Oh definitely i will use double value instead! Maybe the error occurs because I'm adding two annotations to the same location(since I have numerous annotations and float representation truncate the most of my coordinates)?

Comment: Actually, what i did wrong was having invalid latitude values :) Post you answer and i shall accept it!